# nvidia-smi.exe "Insufficient Permissions"

Tags: nvidia, gpu, cntk

My NVidia Quattro 600 GPU is functioning correctly, but running nvidia-smi.exe displays "Insufficient Permissions".

I am executing the command in Administrator Mode, and the drivers are all up to date.

How can I fix the permission's problem?

Running the test mentioned in [How to verify the usage of the GPU?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41613609/how-to-verify-the-usage-of-the-gpu), I get that I am "running on CPU". (Fiddling with the GPU because I am trying to run the CNTK examples.)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [nvidia-smi does not display memory usage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44227767/nvidia-smi-does-not-display-memory-usage)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out that the GPU can't be used to simultaneously do graphics rendering and calculations; for this I'd need a dedicated GPU that doesn't support the monitors at the same time.

Comment: This might be false.  I know from experience that Tesla, Kepler, and GeForce can simultaneously do graphics rendering and compute.  I've also experienced issues with my NVS 315 Quadro interfering with compute, and have not confirmed it can compute and render simultaneously.  Consult the docs.