# Utilising my GTX1050 for tensorflow/keras not allowed as due to WDDM mode

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, nvidia

I recently bought a computer with an NVIDIA GeForce GTX1050. I have been trying to use it with tensorflow and keras through a local jupyter notebook. I have got tensorflow-gpu and keras-gpu in my environment. I have all the correct versions of cuda and cudnn installed with all the necessary paths in my environment variables as per https://www.tensorflow.org/install/gpu. When I run the `nvidia-smi` command I get this:
[output of nvidia-smi](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hkKkq.png). When I look at [output of nvidia-smi -q](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b6bV7.png) it says 'Not available in WDDM driver model'.

After doing some research, it seems all GeForce products support only WDDM, so how do people use their GeForce products with deep learning? I have seen countless youtube videos and forum posts with people claiming the use their GeForce GPU with tensorflow and keras. What am I missing?

Comment: Native environment often causes issues while using GPU. Try installing Anaconda and install all the dependencies in the condo environment and then try to run your code there. As conda installs all the additional dependencies of any package alongside automatically, I hope it fixes your problem.

Comment: @RishabP. this is what I have done from the start, no joy.

Answer (score 0):

Are you concerned that the models are not running in your GPU. This SO question seems similar to what you have https://stackoverflow.com/a/44228331/8416255

Comment: That link says to switch to TCC mode which apparently you can't do with GeForce series GPU, that is my question.

Comment: @CharlieBaskerville I think the link says, tensorflow GPU still works, its just that you cannot monitor it on windows

Comment: I'm not sure it does. There is no speed up in computation time when trying to use the GPU which would suggest that it is not being used.

Comment: What's the result of this? https://stackoverflow.com/a/38019608/8416255